# Codilty, binary gap get the highest gap

Tags: algorithm, go

I have written a solution for the `codility` task which is Binary Gap.
finding the highest gap in Binary. for example 1041 is the input number and convert it to binary the result is 5. here is the code :

```
package codility 

import(
    "strconv"
)

func Solutions(N int) int{
    binary := convertNumberToBinary(N)
    result := getHighestGap(binary)

    return result
}

func convertNumberToBinary(N int)string{
    result := ""

    for N > 0 {
        binary := N%2;
        result = strconv.Itoa(binary) + result
        N = N/2;
    }

    return result
}

func getHighestGap(binary string) int{
    result := 0
    count := 0 
    isCount := false
    stringArray := []byte(binary)

    for i:=0; i < len(stringArray); i++{
        if stringArray[i] == '1' {
            if result < count{
                result = count
            }
            count = 0
            isCount = true
        }else if isCount{
            //found 0
            count ++
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

and the test file :

```
package codility

import(
    "testing"
)

func TestBinrayGap(testing *testing.T){
    var testObjects = []struct{
        input int
        expected int
    }{
        {1041, 5},
        {529, 4},
        {20, 1},
    }

    for _, t := range testObjects {
        actual := Solutions(t.input)
        if actual != t.expected{
            testing.Errorf("Test failed expected : %s, actual : %s", t.expected, actual)
        }
    }
}
```

here I'm converting the input number to binary first and then count the highest length of the gap by converting the string to array byte `[]byte'. And for the test I'm using table driven test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It would have been a good idea to link to the problem statement in your question.
- Please run `gofmt` on your code, typically have your editor automatically format your files every time you save your source file.
- Your naming conventions aren't very Go-like.

  - `Solutions` is too vague, `BinaryGap` would be better.
  - `convertNumberToBinary` is really long; this isn't Java — `toBinary` would largely be enough
  - `stringArray` is very wrong: this variable is a byte slice, plus, it doesn't give you extra information from its type
  - `TestBinryGap` should probably be `TestBinaryGap`
  - `testObjects` is weird and slightly misleading; Go test files usually name this variable `test` or `tc`, and `expected` is pretty much always called `want`
- When you want to append repetitively to a string like in convertNumberToBinary, use `string.Buffer`. But here, why not just use a `[]bool` that you can name `isOne` or something?
- I think the function is simple enough that you can just put it in one function, and compute the binary representation at the same time you compute the binary gap. This would make your memory complexity $(1) instead of O(log(n)) (no need to allocate a slice or a string anymore) and simplify your code.
- You don't need to convert your `string` (or your `[]bool`) into a `[]byte` later on; you can just iterate on it directly.
- You should probably test that the input is a nonnegative number and return an error if that's the case (although maybe this isn't necessary in a competitive programming setting).
- On the positive side, your test is a good idiomatic example of struct-based tests =)

Comment: I really like when you mention about stringArray, and the testObjects

Comment: but one thing that I still don't get it what do you mean by use `[]bool` and name `isOne` ?

Comment: You want to represent a binary number digit by digit. Rather than storing it as e.g. `[]byte("10011")`, you can store it as `[]bool{true, false, false, true, true}`. This way, you give the compiler the option of using only 1 bit by cell rather than 8 =) And you avoid making assumptions on your data: for example, if you store a binary number in a `[]byte`, what if you have a bug and one of your cell ends up containing a different byte than `'0'` or `'1'`? This will be hard to track and debug.

Comment: ooh okay, I see, that's amazing thing suggestion. I can reduce the memory usage  for the variable and would be easier to debug